# Ghost window border won't go away

Tags: macos

A lost window top with no actual window attached to it is stuck on my desktop. How do I get rid of it? I have already tried `killall Dock` and `killall Finder` but unfortunately it's still there.

[image: Window border]

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: And do you know what app that window is from?

Comment: Restarting works, but it comes back after a while. Also I don’t want to have to reboot for something like this. No idea what app it is, I have tried closing everything but it didn’t work.

Comment: Killing the dock and the problem won't fix that problem, you're going to need to know what app it is. Does it just pop up randomly?

Comment: @TLP Check Activity Monitor